# Azure Web App - Front End Not Connecting with Backend

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

After hosting my front and backend applications through Azure Web App, I cannot get my front end to hit an endpoint on my backend. I continuously receive a 400 Bad Request from axios.

This used to be my local endpoint:

> https://localhost:7047/api/forum

Then, I switched out the root URL to what was listed as my URL under the properties section on Azure:

> https://nicksportfolio.azurewebsites.net/api/forum

On my .NET app, my CORS is configured as to allow origin:

```
{
builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

I even went on the CORS section on Azure and set the 'Allowed Origins' to '*' as to allow  access from any source to my endpoint (I'm aware this is a security concern and will change it in the future)

Comment: when you upload to server the local host of the web site is now the server, its doesn't have access to your pc, you also have to upload the api to a server then use the servers public urls

Comment: @EnenDaveyBoy correct - I replaced the local server URL in my axios call with that of the public api URL, as stated in my post. I still receive a 400 response

Comment: sorry I am confused, the url in your op is for an azure website. not an api

Comment: @EnenDaveyBoy Thats the url I received when hosting the api on App Service - am I supposed to be using a different service and/or configure it so that Azure knows its an api?

Comment: firstly try to find out if the api endpoint is working, so put the url in a browser use the debugging console to find out what the response is, if its not found the url is wrong if there is a cors error you need to setup cors or disable cors (not recommended but good to test), once you get it working then implement it into the front end. I don't know how your front end and backend is configured so its hard to say the rest, there are loads of different ways to have it setup, and as long as it works for you

Comment: @EnenDaveyBoy thanks for the advice - I tested it on various endpoints through Postman and I got a 400 response on everything except one endpoint. Its driving me nuts how all of them worked perfectly fine locally. Here is the front and backend implementations between that one endpoint that worked (200) and one of the endpoints that didn't (400): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1og9co0AdFASgEvDApfSIZQ5UK2-21mMJYuJ6aAxD9SA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the good news is the apis seem to be there, but there is an error server side, you will need to look through the log files of the live api's to find out what the problem is, when i upload to the servers, the issues are normally parameters that haven't been set, or permissions for connections have been fully configured, there could also be other issues like azures systems working differently to how you think they work, i had an issue with the authorization level of azure functions not working with identity as i expected.

Comment: @EnenDaveyBoy I think I'm getting closer - I turned on the Log Stream on Azure for my api. After my get request, I got the following: "The request cannot be understood by the server due to malformed syntax": https://docs.google.com/document/d/1og9co0AdFASgEvDApfSIZQ5UK2-21mMJYuJ6aAxD9SA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Glad your getting somewhere, but I can't help you with that I have never had the error so I have no expierence, I thought it be something to the content type not being right, but it seems it could be a lot of different things, from permissions to invalid cookies after a quick google, and I have no idea how to debug it, you might want to start a new question with this issue, now you know a little bit more, good luck hope you get it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs you provided, the 400 Bad Request error in the SignUp endpoint is likely due to a missing or invalid `ProfileImageFile` property in the `UserDto_Creation` object.

The SignUp endpoint is expecting a `multipart/form-data` request with the following properties:

- `Username`
- `Password`
- `Email`
- `ProfileImageFile`  (optional)

If the `ProfileImageFile` property is not present in the request, or if the file is invalid, the API will return a 400 Bad Request error.

To fix the error, you need to make sure that the `ProfileImageFile` property is present in the request, and that the file is valid. You can check the validity of the file by checking the `ContentType` and `ContentLength` properties.

Using below code :

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto_Return>> CreateUser([FromForm] UserDto_Creation newUser)
{
    string? imageUrl = null;

    if (newUser.ProfileImageFile != null && newUser.ProfileImageFile.Length != 0)
    {
        var fileName = newUser.Username + "\\" + DateTime.Now + "\\" + Path.GetExtension(newUser.ProfileImageFile.FileName);
        imageUrl = await _userService.UploadImage(newUser.ProfileImageFile, fileName);
    }

    // Manually map (due to ProfileURL)
    var newUserEntity = new Entities.User.User(newUser.Username, newUser.Password, newUser.Email)
    {
        FirstName = newUser.FirstName,
        LastName = newUser.LastName,
        Bio = newUser.Bio,
        ProfileURL = imageUrl
    };

    await _userRepository.CreateUserAsync(newUserEntity);

    var newUserToReturn = _mapper.Map<Models.User.UserDto_Return>(newUserEntity);

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser",
        new
        {
            username = newUserToReturn.Username,
            password = newUserToReturn.Password
        },
        newUserToReturn);
}
```

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('Username', username);
formData.append('Password', password);
formData.append('Email', email);

if (profileImageFile) {
  formData.append('ProfileImageFile', profileImageFile);
}

axios.post('https://nicksportfolio.azurewebsites.net/api/user', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

- For more details refer toUpload Single And Multiple Files Using The .NET Core 6 Web [API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-single-and-multiple-files-using-the-net-core-6-web-api/).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation, but I still received a 400 response code unfortunately. I think I realize what my issue is - the endpoints where I receive a 400 are the ones that communicate with my SQLite database (I attempted endpoints that didn't utilize this and I receive a 200). I'm currently on a Free F1 tier, and VNET integration, which sets up calls to databases, is only available starting from the basic plan. Does this mean I have no other option but to upgrade?

Comment: Yes, correct. In order to use VNET integration, which is required to set up calls to databases outside of Azure [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration), you will need to upgrade to at least the Basic tier.